# On Windows Server 2012, I cannot connect with IE, but telnet or powershell works just fine

Tags: windows, networking, internet-explorer

On Windows Server 2012R2, I have the following issue:

- I can ping my other (Linux) server
- I can telnet into it on port 80
- I can send a GET /url/ and I receive a response with html (in telnet)
- I can also issue Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile index.html http://my-server-ip/ and get index.html on the Windows machine...

BUT

Internet Explorer refuses to open any page, be it on the said server, or in the internet.

- I have checked that no proxy is set in IE
- I have checked that the Enhanced Security Configuration of IE is off (which it is)

The windows assistant just tells me that the web server is not responding (which is false, as the telnet experiment shows).

What could be the problem?

EDIT:

It finally got solved, but I don't know why. Someone connected with Administrator privileges, launched IE on the url, and... it worked. Then I connected with my user, and... it worked... So, any explanation would be welcome! (maybe some initialization that needs admin rights to operate ??)

Comment: Is IE Enhanced Security Configuration turned on? Try turning it off in the dashboard and trying again if it is.

Comment: To elaborate on Catatonic's suggestion here's a step by step guide about disabling the internet explorer enhanced security configuration via commandline and via Server Manager: http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/11/28/how-to-disable-ie-enhanced-security-in-windows-server-2012/

Comment: @megamorf thanks for the link. I re-checked using these instructions, and can confirm IE ESC is off...

Comment: Have you configured any outbound firewall settings on the server? Does your router block any requests from your server's IP? Do you use a proxy server?

Comment: @BigChris no, windows firewall is off, and I've checked IE is not using any proxy in its settings. Moreover, I _can_ have http dialog with the other server using telnet or Invoke-WebRequest, so I don't think the problem is in networking...

Comment: Have you tried resetting the IE advanced settings?

Comment: @BigChris just did a reset, to no avail

Comment: What happens if you add your Linux server's IP/hostname to your Server 2012's Trusted sites?

Comment: If you have the access something that will almost certainly tell you what's going on is a packet capture. It could be a proxy or an MTU issue or some other random networking problem. Can you install Wireshark on the machine and do a packet capture of IE attempting to access the machine?

Comment: It finally got solved, but I don't know why. Someone connected with Administrator privileges, launched IE on the url, and... it worked. Then I connected with my user, and... it worked... So, any explanation would be welcome! (maybe some initialization that needs admin rights to operate ??)